# Как добавить фильтрацию по дате WordPress поиск?

Tags: wordpress

у нас есть стандартный поиск WordPRess. Вопрос как добавить еще в параметры поиск по дате( от и до ), без использования сторонних плагинов?

Comment: По какой дате вы хотите сортировать? Это дата создания, изменения или доп. поле?

Comment: Дате создания, как и со стандартным WP

Comment: Укажите это в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаете нужную форму с указанием даты. Для поиска лучше использовать передачу данных через GET-запрос. Поправьте стандартный вывод `get_search_form` формы для поиска:

```
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'my_search_form' );
function my_search_form( $form ) {
    $s          = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 's', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ?? '';
    $date_start = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'date_start', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ?? '';
    $date_end   = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'date_end', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ?? '';
    ob_start(); ?>
    <form action="<?php home_url( '/' ) ?>" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $s ) ?>">
        <input type="text" name="date_start" id="date_start" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $date_start ) ?>">
        <input type="text" name="date_end" id="date_end" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $date_end ) ?>">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Найти"/>
    </form>

    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Затем на `pre_get_posts` добавьте date_query по данным из $_GET. Пример:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_date_query_to_search' );
function add_date_query_to_search( $wp_query ) {
    if ( $wp_query->is_search() && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
        $start_date = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'start_date', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $end_date   = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'end_date', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $date_query = [];
        if ( $start_date ) {
            $date_query[] = [
                'column'    => 'post_date_gmt',
                'after'     => $start_date,
                'inclusive' => true,
            ];
        }
        if ( $end_date ) {
            $date_query[] = [
                'column'    => 'post_date_gmt',
                'before'    => $end_date,
                'inclusive' => true,
            ];
        }
        if ( ! empty( $date_query ) ) {
            $wp_query->set( 'date_query', $date_query );
        }
    }
}
```